# XML parsing using JDOM

Tags: xml, parsing

I am trying to parse xml using JDOM. The problem is i want split a huge xml file into smaller files. The huge xml contains many `<page></page>`. I want to treat each `<page></page>` as a page. I am not able to find a function which could just copy the everything from `<page>`,`</page>` to different files.

```
Out0.xml
<page>
</page>

out1.xml
<page>
</page>
```

Brute options are to go through each tag copying every data, but that is boring. Is there a way I could copy all bytes within `<page>`,`<page>` different pages? Is there a function similar to `VTD-xml::getXML().getBytes();`

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a task for XSLT or StAX more than JDOM. If the original file is truly huge, JDOM's actually very memory intensive and that route likely won't work.

Comment: I had considered XSLT and StAX but just wanted to be consistent with my code where i have used JDOM for parsing. I will try using XSLT/Stax. But, if there is a better option do let me know ?

Comment: I guess in XML parsing APIs, there are a lot of tradeoffs on ease of use vs. speed and memory consumption, and unfortunately, you might need to be flexible sometimes if the situation warrants it.